# Is it actually safe to use sha1 for AWS S3 signing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3, sign

> The Signature element is the RFC 2104 HMAC-SHA1 of selected elements
>   from the request.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#ConstructingTheAuthenticationHeader

But wikipedia says that sha1 is not safe anymore:

> As of 2020, chosen-prefix attacks against SHA-1 are now practical[8]
>   as such, it is recommended to remove SHA-1 from products as soon as
>   possible and use instead SHA-256 or SHA-3. Replacing SHA-1 is urgent
>   where it is used for signatures.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1

There is also a benchmark where a guy bruteforces sha1 at a speed of 68771.0 MH/s!
https://gist.github.com/epixoip/a83d38f412b4737e99bbef804a270c40

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SHA-1 and HMAC-SHA1 are not the same thing and in certain use-cases, HMAC-SHA1 is still considered secure. Have a look at this question: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26510/why-is-hmac-sha1-still-considered-secure

Comment: This is correct, but this algorithm still shouldn't be used for an entirely different reason.  As noted at the top of the page of the AWS docs, only the oldest AWS regions ever supported it... so, e.g., code relying on this algorithm would work in us-east-1 but not in us-east-2.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - your comment should be an answer, pointing the OP (and anyone else) at the v4 signature and recommending that the v2 signature not be used.